# How to use data you've just filled before submitting it in an infopath form?

Tags: 2010, infopath, database-connection, submit

I have an infopath form binded with a list. In this infopath form there are several fields to fill. When the user press the submit button, I want the view to change if the values of the fields the user has just changed are strange compared to the previous one. I can set up these rules on the submit button but the fact is I cannot use the values of the fields the user's just changed without submitting it, in the conditions of my rules... If I submit those values, in that case, I won't be able to compare with the previous one. Do you think it's possible to use the value the user has just filled in the conditions of my rules?

Comment: so you don't want it to be submitted when the values are "strange compared to the previous one"?

Comment: Yes! I don't want to submit it in that case

Answer (score 0):

So there is an option to remove the submit-button for users and create a button yourself which has actions happening before you submit.

You can disable the submit button via Form Options, then Web Browser -> remove the Submit Option. Or you can disable the whole submitting from the user via Submit Options -> remove User can submit this form.

Then you create a button in your form called "Submit" and set a rule which allows to submit, in your case, all the data is not "strange" and then choose the action "submit data".